# EasyPHP 5.3.9 - can't run php from windows console

Tags: php, windows, easyphp

I decided to upgrade my easyphp server, and after installing found that I can't run php from console anymore, for some reason when tried to install pear, I get an error box. The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this  problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling easyphp completely and delete all remaning files after uninstalling, sometimes they don't get deleted all, so you have to do it manually, then reinstall it and see if that works